# Magento 2: Add form fields to checkout form and attach JavaScript

Tags: checkout

I would like to add a button to the checkout form just below the address fields. The purpose of this will be to get a list of possible address from the users postcode through an API. I will also need to add some JavaScript/jQuery to the form which can't be done in the conventional way since the form is generated by Knockout.js and is loaded after the DOM has finished loading.

I'd be grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction and advise what sort of approach I should be taking here. Maybe there is an example that is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Many thanks